# BPX2OPN fails when trying to open existing file for read/stat

Tags: assembly, zos

I am trying to use the BPX2OPN service to open an existing HFS file and determine how many bytes are in it. The examples I have found are only for *creating* a file and not opening an existing one, but I *assume* I can use it to open an existing file as well.

Here is the code I am using:

```
        USING PARMS,R1
        L   R10,PPATHL
        ST  R10,PATHLEN
        L   R9,PPATHA
        ST  R9,PATHNAME
        LA  R8,STAT#LENGTH
        ST  R8,STATL
        XC  S_MODE,S_MODE
        MVI S_MODE2,S_IRUSR
        XC  O_FLAGS(OPNF#LENGTH),O_FLAGS
        MVI O_FLAGS4,O_RDONLY

        L   R2,0(,R9)
        L   R3,4(,R9)
        L   R4,8(,R9)
        L   R5,12(,R9)
        L   R6,16(,R9)

        CALL  BPX2OPN,                                                 x
               (PATHLEN,                                               x
               PATHNAME,                                               x
               O_FLAGS,                                                x
               S_MODE,                                                 x
               STATL,                                                  x
               STAT,                                                   x
               RV,                                                     x
               RC,                                                     x
               RN),MF=(E,BPXOPND)
        L     R7,RV
        L     R8,RC
        L     R9,RN
        LA 0,27
        ST 0,0(,0)
```

where I force an abend after the call. My code is 31-bit AMODE. I am seeing the following registers:

```
D                                           406 00000010     DATA AT PSW  26908F58 - 001B5000  0000BFAF  B06C4740
D                                           406 00000010     AR/GR 0: 00000000/00000000_0000001B   1: 00000002/00000000_00000072
D                                           406 00000010           2: 00000000/00000000_4B4B6184   3: 00000000/00000000_81A38161
D                                           406 00000010           4: 00000000/00000000_A2859989   5: 00000000/00000000_85A24BA3
D                                           406 00000010           6: 00000000/00000000_A7A30000   7: 00000000/00000000_FFFFFFFF
D                                           406 00000010           8: 00000000/00000000_00000079   9: 00000000/00000000_0594003A
D                                           406 00000010           A: 00000000/00000000_00000012   B: 00000000/00000000_2690CE40
D                                           406 00000010           C: 00000000/00000000_A6908E8E   D: 00000000/00000000_2690CE40
D                                           406 00000010           E: 00000000/00000000_A6908F4A   F: 00000000/00000050_00000000
```

Looking at the registers, R7 indicates a failure (-1), R8 is the return code (0x79) which is **EINVAL** and the right byte of R9 (the reason code) is 0x3A which seems to indicate that I have a [NULL in my path name](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=errnojrs-zos-unix-reason-codes) but if you look at R2,R3,R4,R5,R6 there are no NULLs (it is *../data/series.txt* in EBCDIC). I thought perhaps I needed the address of the length instead of the length stored in the parm list, but doing that gives me an **EBADADDR** code.
Any suggestions on how I have coded this wrong, or if perhaps I can't use this service, is appreciated.

Comment: I am getting the same failure trying to use the example: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=31-bpx2opn-openstat-example which I have here: https://github.com/MikeFultonDev/aoc2023/blob/main/puzzles/day09/p1/src/crtfile.asm
I had to code up my own _STATL_ set up.

Comment: <<- I did get the sample working. But still haven't got my original program to work.

Comment: Small point is that if you just want the size of the file, "stat" (BPX1STA/BPX4STA) is usually much better than opening a file and reading through it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem eventually

I was storing the wrong thing into `PATHNAME` - I was storing a pointer into PATHNAME, which the macro was loading the address of, instead of just using the address directly. So, instead of:

```
ST  R9,PATHNAME
```

I should instead have just loaded up R9 (or some other register) and referenced it directly in the macro, e.g.

```
       CALL  BPX2OPN,                                                 x
               (PATHLEN,                                               x
               (R9),                                                   x
               O_FLAGS,                                                x
               S_MODE,                                                 x
               STATL,                                                  x
               STAT,                                                   x
               RV,                                                     x
               RC,                                                     x
               RN),MF=(E,BPXOPND)
```

which works fine and the call is succeeding.

Comment: My Thanks to @aidan (https://github.com/AidoP) who pointed me in the right direction!